# SAML IdP or SP, which do I need

Tags: php, wordpress, single-sign-on, saml

I want to set up a Portal for consumers. 
This portal has to have multiple buttons to go to other locations, for example Google and Wordpress.
This by means of SSO, I found out that SAML is best practice for this.
I'm only wondering and  trying to find out if my application has to be an IdP (Identity Provider) or an SP (Service Provider).
This application will be made in PHP per request of the client.

### Edit

I've looked into simpleSaml, Because the answers I got are good but not concluding. In essention I want this http://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/PF610/IdP-Initiated+SSO--POST with a client portal and I want to go from the client portal to Google analytics, Magento, Wordpress and some local other websites

Comment: You can be both IDp and SP. Where do you fetch login information? If from Google, then you are SP and Google is IDP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IDP authetnicates the users, the SPs then trust the IDP to have authenticated the users correctly.

If your users will authenticate on your site, you will be the IDP. If on the other hand the users log in to google, andyou then trust google for authentication, you will be the SP

Comment: The users will authenticate on my site with their login information they got, then they can go from there to google and login 1 time and then go there every time after that.

Answer (score 1):

IDP stands for **Identity Provider** who has users information and stores the users databases.

SP stands for **Service Provider** who allows the users to use its service by getting authenticated from their IDP.

A simple flow is:-

1. User wants to access the SP website.
2. SP redirect the user to IDP to log in on IDP.
3. Once User is successfully logged in there IDP redirect the user to SP with success response.
4. If SP gets a success response from IDP it allows user access to it.

*Now if you got the flow you can easily derive that Google cannot be used as SP has it already contains user database and don't provide the user provisioning (Creation of user at run time).*

So with Google,  **You will be SP and Google will be IDP**.

*Wordpress provide user provisioning and can be used both as SP and IDP.*

So with Wordpress,

1. If you want your user to login in Wordpress, **You will be IDP and Wordpress will be SP**. You can try this [plugin](https://plugins.miniorange.com/wordpress-single-sign-on-sso/) to achieve it.
2. If you want Wordpress user to login on your site. **You will be SP and Wordpress will be IDP**. You can try this [plugin](https://plugins.miniorange.com/wordpress-saml-idp/) to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You are the IDP and Google/Wordpress are SPs

Comment: I did not get why the answer was downvoted. It is the right answer to the question.

Comment: "The users will authenticate on my site " - I suspect this means that the users log into their Intranet when they come to work?, "they can go from there to Google and login 1 time" - so they are actually logging into the application with Google - so Google is the IDP/

Comment: they log in to my site (with my site credentials) and when they press a button to go to google, they will need to provide their login information (for google) once and after that whenever they use the portal they can automatically log in to google without providing user credentials

Comment: I think it boils down to this question, who creates a SAML response and who consumes it. From the discussion here I definitely believe that it is not you who will be consuming the responses. And as per the description "you enter google credentials once", this is for mapping account at your end to a Google account. After that you will never have to re-enter your credentials. Clearly Google is the SP here, and if you are using OneLogin then it is the IDP.